# When did IIF amount formats change and how can I get it back to old format?

Tags: accounting, quickbooks

How does the IIF export from Accounting Batches get its information to determine the format of the amounts?  Batches created before 5.34 export simple value amounts:

```
12.00
-12.00
```

Batches after the upgrade to 5.34 adds a dollar sign to the amount:

```
$12.00
-$12.00
```

I can't get these files imported without loading them into Excel and changing the formatting.  How can I get the amounts to return to the earlier format?  What changed in Civi to cause this?

Answer (score 2):

There's been some changes to support php 7.4 which doesn't have money_format() and also some work towards locales. Most likely that's the cause. I'd open a lab ticket.

I'd guess this line needs to be changed to match the other changes that have happened:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/33307b5a0da280c63ed0d8fa1f8a3e899a217ad0/CRM/Financial/BAO/ExportFormat/IIF.php#L354

Like this example: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19602/files

Answer (score 0):

It seemed at first this was due to a customization, and was not able to be replicated on dmaster. We have changed this output file however to better support the right number of digits for the localized currency, and appropriate rounding. Eventually problem was isolated to new code that runs when php-intl library is available, and fix merged into 5.34.

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/-/issues/166

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect.  The result still occurs even with the removal of the customization. The issue is still open, and some people have replicated it in some fashion.